# Atalho no editor que permita abrir o HTML no Navegador

Tags: sublime-text

Estou estudando *html* e *javascript*, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma dentro do **sublime** que ao pressionar por exemplo f12, o arquivo posso ser aberto diretamente por algum navegador. Sem a necessidade de salvar o arquivo e clicar nela no diretório e pedir para abrir como.

Comment: Acho que isso https://browsersync.io/ resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser

- No sublimetext abra o *Package Control* (use o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
- Então selecione *Install Package*
- Após isto digite `View in Browser`

Após instalado abra um documento html e aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, irá abrir o documento no seu browser principal.

### Configurando múltiplos navegadores

Para configurar multiplos navegadores vá no seguinte menu: <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Key Bindings</kbd>

Então edite o documento para algo semelhante a isto:

```
[
    { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+v" ], "command": "view_in_browser" },
    { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+f" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "firefox" } },
    { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+c" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "chrome" } },
    { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+i" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "iexplore" } },
    { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+s" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "safari" } }
]
```

É claro que para funcionar terá precisa ter os navegadores instalados, então assim poderá configurar os navegadores que desejar.

Answer (score -1):

Crie um atalho da seguinte forma: na barra de navegação do sublime click em preferences>key bindings
Aparecerá uma nova janela mostrando os atalhos padrões do editor em uma coluna e outra terá um para você usuário adicionar atalhos. Adicione o seguinte atalho:
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "open_in_browser" },
Tu pode usar outras teclas também como exemplo ["ctrl+shift+f12"], apenas verifique se o atalho ainda não foi usado pois são muitos já definidos.